# How to center variable length submit buttons?

Tags: html, css

The following `input type=submit` buttons within and outside a `div` element centers with `margin: auto` when viewed in Firefox but not in Google Chrome:

HTML:

```
<div>
 <input type=submit value=submit>
</div>
<input type=submit value=submit>
text continues from here...
```

CSS:

```
div {
 width: 200px;
 background: green;
}

input {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
}
```

According to **W3C**, is there a correct behaviour? And how does one centers it in Google Chrome noting that the width has to be a variable and that the button has to be cleared from the text below?

Comment: Are you trying to make something that renders in Chrome like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sHcJP/) does in Firefox? If so, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sHcJP/1/) is how.

Comment: @thirtydot: I am trying get some consistency in the presentation of the form. It looks weird for the button to be not at the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are not defining a width on input so it is not doing the auto margins.

`INPUT` is an inline element so it is easiest styled with ways that style inline elements, eg a `text-align: center` on the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/wU5tb/ is a fiddle showing the effects of putting `text-align: center` on the two relevant parent elements (div and body).

Because this is styling the parent element you may find yourself needing to put in some extra block elements (eg `p` or `div` as appropriate) to take the centering style.

I've tested this on chrome, firefox and IE and all behave as expected.

Comment: I agree that this will work if I apply the text-align center on the form element or the body element. Not sure if there is a cleaner solution, if not I would have to apply another layer of wrapper. But I do have many forms. I hope there is a better alternative.

Comment: It may be that your original approach could work if you could explicitly set a width. Given its dynamic this would have to be done via JS but I'm not sure that could get the right thing. Of course, if you are doing it with JS you could put a marker class on and then use jQuery to find those elements and `wrap` an appropriate div with the rigth style on around them...

Answer (score -1):

Use `align="center"` for your div contents/button to be centered.

```
<div align="center">
   <input type=submit value=submit>
</div>
```

## Update

## [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oyutoq)

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. And you missed out the second button.

Comment: Is this equivalent to using `text-align: center;` for those wanting to avoid these sorts of attributes?

Comment: your's is not working i tried here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/P9fQD/

Comment: Is it the same code as what you have written? It didn't work on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MALj5/3/).

Comment: @Sarfraz I also tried here this not working. i used same what you have used. http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/P9fQD/2/

Comment: @SureshPattu, yes, I concur with you.